# Hibernate 6.2 and json navigation

Tags: java, json, hibernate

I've read in this official article that we can use "." to navigate inside JSON document since Hibernate 6.2:
https://in.relation.to/2023/02/13/hibernate-orm-62-composite-aggregates/

However when I tried to do that I got the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Could not interpret attribute 'address' of basic-valued path 'model.City(c).cityInfo'
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.domain.SqmBasicValuedSimplePath.resolvePathPart(SqmBasicValuedSimplePath.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.DomainPathPart.resolvePathPart(DomainPathPart.java:42)
```

Here's my mapping:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Table
@Entity
public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;
    
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private CityInfo cityInfo;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class CityInfo implements Serializable {
        
        private String address;
        
        private int population;
    }
}
```

And the query itself:

```java
TypedQuery<City> query = em.createQuery(
        "SELECT c FROM City c WHERE "
        + "c.cityInfo.address = :address", City.class);
                
query.setParameter("address", "test");
System.out.println(query.getResultList());
```

Comment: Just to be sure. Which database are you using? Does it support JSON?

Comment: According to the document you have shared the CityInfo would be an embeddable struct and not a static class.

Comment: @Mar-Z Yes, it supports JSON (MySQL) and I can execute native SQL query using Hibernate: SELECT * FROM City c WHERE c.cityInfo->"$.address"=?

Answer (score 2):

I just added `@Embeddable` annotation to the json pojo
In your case it will look like

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Embeddable
public static class CityInfo implements Serializable {
    
    private String address;
    
    private int population;
}
```

In my case following HQL
`... extraAttributes.id = '2947d5da-f175-4386-8a8f-9a3f2aa1ef9e'`
was transformed to next where clause (postgres)

````
where
   cast(p1_0.extraAttributes->>'id' as varchar(255))='2947d5da-f175-4386-8a8f-9a3f2aa1ef9e'```
````