# Hibernate 6.2.1 and json navigation @Embeddable

Tags: hibernate, hql, jsonb, embeddable

I am using Wildfly 28, Hibernate 6.2.1
I want to use HQL to a Json Object like in this article: [Hibernate 6.2.1 and json navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75908673/hibernate-6-2-and-json-navigation)

When i add @Embeddable, the following exception is thrown on application startup. Can you help please?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.sql.model.ast.builder.ColumnValuesTableMutationBuilder.addValueColumn(org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.SelectableMapping)" because "mutationBuilder" is null
at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.sql.model.ast.builder.MutationGroupBuilder.accept(MutationGroupBuilder.java:80)
at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.EmbeddableMappingTypeImpl.forEachInsertable(EmbeddableMappingTypeImpl.java:709)
at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EmbeddableValuedModelPart.forEachInsertable(EmbeddableValuedModelPart.java:141)
at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.lambda$applyTableInsertDetails$9(InsertCoordinator.java:378)
at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.sql.model.ast.builder.MutationGroupBuilder.lambda$forEachTableMutationBuilder$0(MutationGroupBuilder.java:71)
at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:729)
at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.sql.model.ast.builder.MutationGroupBuilder.forEachTableMutationBuilder(MutationGroupBuilder.java:71)
at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.applyTableInsertDetails(InsertCoordinator.java:367)
at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.generateStaticOperationGroup(InsertCoordinator.java:346)
at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.<init>(InsertCoordinator.java:75)
at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.buildInsertCoordinator(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3298)
at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLateInit(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3081)
at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3325)
at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:204)
at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.initializeMappingModel(SessionFactoryImpl.java:319)
at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:269)
at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:431)
at org.hibernate@6.2.1.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1455)
... 12 more
```

I try to add @Embeddable to avoid the

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Could not interpret attribute 'xxx' of basic-valued path 'model.yy(c).yyInfo'
```

But the mentioned NullPointer exception is occured.